# Is there a function that returns Key along with Value?

Tags: functions

Consider an `Association`:

```
assoc = <|"a"-><|"a1"-><|"a11"->1,"a12"->2,""->3|>,"a2"-><|"a21"->4,""->5|>|>,"b"-><|"b1"-><|""->6,"b11"->7|>|>|>
```

Suppose I want to sum all the Values of Key `""` at level 2 but I want to return as an association.

If I do something like:

```
Query[Total,Total,""]@assoc
```

Which is equivalent to

```
Query[Total,Total,Lookup[""]]@assoc
```

I get `14` but I want it to return `<|""->14|>`.

My Question: is there a function / operator form `f` such that `Query[Total,Total,f]@assoc` returns `<|""->14|>`.

One possible solution here is `Query[Total,Total,{""}]@assoc` but this does not generalizes to arbitrary levels.

In short is there a way to lookup a `Key` in an `Association` but not return just the value but the `Sub-Association`.

Comment: Can you give an example where your `Query[Total,Total,{""}]@assoc` suggestion doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean your solution doesn't generalize to arbitrary levels? That would have appeared to be the way to go to me.

Comment: `assoc[[{"k1","k2"}]]` and `KeyTake[assoc, {"k1", "k2"}]` both take a sub-association.

Comment: I voted to close as "can't be answered without additional code/info" because we can't proceed until the comments above are addressed. (Ping me if you edit the question, I'll remove the close vote then.)